# pubnub clear message to a "chipered" channel

Tags: encryption, pubnub

new on PubNub and got interested into it. Trying some simple example to understand

```
from Pubnub import Pubnub
import sys

SUB_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx"
PUB_KEY = "yyyyyyyyyy"
CHIPER_KEY = "zzzzzzzzz"
channel = 'hello_world'


pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key=PUB_KEY, subscribe_key=SUB_KEY, cipher_key=CHIPER_KEY,ssl_on=True)

# Listen for Messages
def callback(message, channel):
    try:
       if message == "":
            print ("message not valid")
       else:
            print(message)
            if message['text'] == "close":
                pubnub.unsubscribe(channel=channel)
    except:
        print ("xxx")

def error(message):
    print("ERROR : " + str(message))


def connect(message):
    print("CONNECTED")


def reconnect(message):
    print("RECONNECTED")


def disconnect(message):
    print("DISCONNECTED")

try:
    pubnub.subscribe(channel, callback=callback, error=error, connect=connect, reconnect=reconnect, disconnect=disconnect)
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

I have this simple server subscribing to a channel and printing out received messages.
Now I have enabled encryption and in one case everything works finer and in a second case it doesn't work. more details

Just imagine for a second that a malicious user get hold of my PUB_KEY and channel name he can publish messages to my channel. However he doesn't know my CHIPER_KEY (this is not hosted anywhere, I have generated and I control it)

In such case my server below crash:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pubnub.py", line 1281, in run
    _invoke(self.pubnub.latest_sub_callback['callback'], data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pubnub.py", line 1254, in _invoke
    func(get_data_for_user(data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pubnub.py", line 1074, in sub_callback
    _invoke(chobj['callback'], self.decrypt(r),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pubnub.py", line 544, in decrypt
    message = self.pc.decrypt(self.cipher_key, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pubnub.py", line 156, in decrypt
    plain = self.depad(cipher.decrypt(decodestring(msg)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict
```

my understanding here is that this is failing as the received message (which is in clear) is a dict and binascii.a2b_base64(s) called by pubnub.py is expecting a string (in case the message is encrypted is a string)

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

thanks a lot
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

It should certainly not crash on cipher text, thats a bug, and we'll fix it ASAP!

In the meantime, to mitigate against users getting a hold of your publish key, you can use PAM to further nail down publish (or subscribe access) to channels:

https://github.com/pubnub/python/tree/master/python#grant

More info on how PAM and PubNub security in general also available here: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/overview/security.html

geremy

Comment: Geremy,thnx for quick reply. PAM is certainly the right way to go as suggested by you. Antonio